# Sites Data Licenses and High Volume Portal Licenses

Tags: customer-portal, mobile, licenses, force.com-sites

I'm working with an Architect who has a client with High Volume Licenses that wants to develop a new site for use by contract employees to submit forms related to Opportunity and also view Calendar Events as well as Contact information. Normally, as I understand it High Volume Portal Licenses can normally only see Cases. They can see Accounts and Contacts through custom pages, but not through standard ones. Does that also apply to Opportunities?

My next question relates to submitting forms and data related to Opportunities. I'm aware from the [User License Types page](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm) there's also a Data.com user license that allows a user to import or export a limited number of records per month. Could those possibly be used to allow these contractors to submit their opportunity related report forms through a portal? We're talking about approx 300 hundred users that will only use the portal on an average of 3 or 4 times per month and it really doesn't make financial sense to purchase full partner license seats for them.

In summary, can we expose Opportunities and Events through custom pages using a High Volume Portal Licenses? Can those users submit forms with that license or will they need a data.com user license in addition in order to be able to access and submit the data?

Finally, has anyone here run into a similar situation to what I've described? If so, what was your solution? As a related question, we want users to be able to access this via mobile devices. Can they use Mobile lite or do we need to implement the HTML5 Mobile API on all of our pages too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can read on the following pages

http://blog.force365.com/2012/08/08/hvpu-record-access/
http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm

HVPU is not the license to go if you want to grant direct access to Opps and Events.

For client projects we often use proxy (custom) objects to hold just enough information the portal users need to work with and use then custom code to map their inputs against the target object via a future call.

just make your pages mobile ready and you dont need dedicated mobile licenses, especially since the SFDC mobile apps are not best of bread.

Comment: Thanks, what you've described is essentially what I've told the architect I think we'll need to do if we use the HVP license and is also what he's adamantly expressed he wants to avoid! LOL!